# crontab is not working properly with scrapy

Tags: cron, scrapy

I've set crontab to execute scrapy script, but It is not work.
then I attempt same command in terminal. but It is work well.

```
 rankAuction
```

crontab:

```
$ crontab -l
*/10 * * * * cd ~/PRG/tutorials/tutorials/spiders && scrapy crawl nodecrawler
```

How can i solve this issue? please answer this question

thank you

Comment: (1) Try to use full path instead of using `~` sign (2) Is the given path the path of your Scrapy project? Because `scrapy crawl` command has to be launched from there.

Comment: Try changing command to `/bin/bash -lc "cd ~/PRG/tutorials/tutorials/spiders && scrapy crawl nodecrawler" >> /tmp/cron.log` and see what your get in your `/tmp/cron.log` file

Answer (score 1):

Check your Cron logs to see whats going on

```
 grep CRON /var/log/syslog
```

You must be getting `Unknown command Scrapy` or similar error

I am sure its because `Scrapy` is not in `PATH`

To fix it, do this

In your Terminal type `echo $PATH`

Copy the output and then go into `crontab -l`

Now at the top of that file do this

```
PATH=<PASTE WHAT YOU COPIED IN LAST STEP>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your crontab does not know scrapy location

`which scrapy` will tell you the location of scrapy e.g. "/usr/local/bin/scrapy"

Change to `*/10 * * * * cd ~/PRG/tutorials/tutorials/spiders && /usr/local/bin/scrapy crawl nodecrawler > /var/log/cronscrapy.log  2>&1`

`/usr/local/bin/scrapy` will make scrapy work properly

`> /var/log/cronscrapy.log` will create a log at "val/log/cronscrapy.log" when your cron will run

`2>&1` will output both standard output and error if any to the "cronscrapy.log"

Hope it helps someone
`